# Creating a Linux process in C++

Tags: c++, linux, process, fork

So, I need to create a process in linux with fork.
The child process needs to run the Sort program, and pass the "1" to it.
Here's the code I'm trying to make work:

```
int main(){
  cout<<"Master #process: "<<getpid()<<"#parent process:"<<getppid()<<endl;
  char* cmd[2];
  cmd[0]="./Sort";
  cmd[1]="1";
  pid_t child_id=fork();

  if(child_id==0){
    execv(cmd[0],cmd);
  }
    cout<<child_id<<endl;
```

However, when I try to run it in the linux console, it only shows the first string and does not run Sort.

Comment: Maybe you want to wait for the process to finish befored exiting the parent process?

Comment: Do you have an executable called "Sort" (with a capital "S") in the working directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in C++, there is no way to mark the size of an array, other than a terminator, you need to terminate your array with a NULL.

```
char* cmd[3];
cmd[0]="./Sort";
cmd[1]="1";
cmd[2]=NULL;
```

Comment: My guess is that this will not entirely solve the problems, since there is still nothing to make sure the master process waits for the sort to finish.

Comment: @Mats Petersson, unless the intent was to daemonize the process.

Comment: As far as I know, normal `sort` does not have code inside it to create daemon, and the code above does not do the relevant closing of inputs/outputs, that you'd expect in that case.